# Creating a truth-table using intel assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to create a truth table for the function F=(A&B) XOR (C&D'). I'm using Intel assembly language and the whole code has to be fairly short.

The main problem that I keep running into is with the loop to manipulate the variables A,B,C and D to create all the possible inputs of a truth table. The way this would be typically done is to act like the variables are each a bit of a 4 bit binary number and count from 0 to 15, implementing each possible input. I only have 4 registers a stack and RAM memory to accomplish this so I assigned each variable to a register, and I use ram to store a counter and the outputs of the table. I can't think of a good way to do this with a loop, but I have to use one because the simulator I'm using won't function with code as long as mine has become. (It's 256 bytes)

Here is the code, the subroutine called procedure 60 is the piece I want to condense. I don't have to actually output a truth table just tell how many "Minterm's" (outputs of 1) are produced by it.

```
        ;MAIN
    MOV AL,0    ;INITIALIZING VARIABLES
    MOV BL,0
    MOV CL,0
    MOV DL,0
    MOV [20],AL ;INITIALIZE CURRENT NUMBER OF MINTERMS WITH 0
    MOV [21],AL ;INITIALIZE COUNTER WITH 0
LOOP:   CALL    30
    CALL    60
    MOV [21],CL
    CMP CL,15
    JS  LOOP
    CALL    E0
    MOV AL,[20] ;MOVE NUMBER OF MINTERMS TO AL
    MOV [FF],AL ;OUPUT NUMBER OF MINTERMS TO VDU(LOCATIONS [C0] TO [FF])

        ;PROCEDURE 30, IMPLEMENTS THE GIVEN BOOLEAN FUNCTION
    ORG 30  ;WRITE CODE BEGINNING AT [30]
    PUSH    DL  ;CURRENT VALUE OF D
    PUSH    CL  ;CURRENT VALUE OF C
    PUSH    AL  ;CURRENT VALUE OF A, IMPLEMENTING FUNCTION WON'T CHANGE D
    AND AL,BL   ;PERFORMS (AL AND BL), STORES VALUE IN AL
    NOT DL  ;INVERSE OF DL STORED IN DL
    AND CL,DL   ;PERFORMS (CL AND DL), STORES VALUE IN CL
    XOR AL,CL   ;PERFORMS (AL XOR CL), STORES VALUE IN AL
    MOV BL,[20] ;MOVES CURRENT NUMBER OF MINTERMS TO BL
    ADD AL,BL   ;ADD TO CURRENT NUMBER OF MINTERMS IF MINTERM RESULTED FROM FUNCTION
    MOV [20],AL ;STORE NEW CURRENT NUMBER OF MINTERMS
    MOV CL,[21] ;MOVE COUNTER TO CL
    INC CL  ;INCREMENT CL, INCREMENTING COUNTER
    MOV [21],CL ;MOVE NEW VALUE OF COUNTER
    POP AL  ;RESTORE PREVIOUS VALUE OF D
    POP CL  ;RESTORE PREVIOUS VALUE OF C
    POP DL  ;RESTORE PREVIOUS VALUE OF A
    RET

        ;PROCEDURE 60, MANIPULATES VARIABLES TO IMPLEMENT FULL TRUTH TABLE
    ORG 60  ;WRITE CODE BEGINNING AT [60]
    MOV CL,[21] ;MOVE COUNTER VALUE TO CL REGISTER
    CMP CL,1    ;NEED TO MAKE THIS INTO A LOOP
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,2
    JZ  SECOND
    CMP CL,3
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,4
    JZ  FOURTH
    CMP CL,5
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,6
    JZ  SECOND
    CMP CL,7
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,8
    JZ  EIGHTH
    CMP CL,9
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,10
    JZ  SECOND
    CMP CL,11
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,12
    JZ  FOURTH
    CMP CL,13
    JZ  FIRST
    CMP CL,14
    JZ  SECOND
    CMP CL,15
    JZ  FIRST
    JMP LAST
FIRST:
    MOV AL,1
    JMP LAST
SECOND:
    MOV AL,0
    MOV BL,1
    JMP LAST
FOURTH:
    MOV AL,0
    MOV BL,0
    MOV CL,1
    JMP LAST
EIGHTH:
    MOV AL,0
    MOV BL,0
    MOV CL,0
    MOV DL,1
    JMP LAST
LAST:
    RET

        FINISH:
    ORG E0              ;WRITE CODE BEGINNING AT E0(OUTPUTS TO VDU)
    DB  "The number of Minterms in F is"    ;OUTPUT STATEMENT
    RET

        END
```

Comment: you can try pcemu.  I have a fork just for basic x86 assembly http://github.com/dwelch67/pcemu_samples

Comment: use one register and count from 0 to 15, use AND and jz or jnz to determine each bit and go from there. there are many solutions to this it doesnt take much code or registers...

Comment: if this is a homework assignment please add the homework tag, if this is x86 assembly please add the x86 tag.

Comment: @dwelch Yeah in the code I used a counter and jz, but I want to use a more efficient method for the jz loop. It seems like I should be able to do this using less jz instructions, instead of 15 (one for each case) as I'm using now. That's my main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply:

```
mov cl, 0 ; CL contains DCBA bits
L:
mov bl, cl ; BL contains DCBAb
and bl, 101b ; BL contains 0C0Ab
mov al, cl ; AL contains DCBAb
shr al, 1 ; AL contains 0DCBb
and al, 101b ; AL contains 0D0Bb
and bl, al ; BL contains 0(C&D)0(A&B)b
mov al, bl ; AL contains 0(C&D)0(A&B)b
and bl, 1 ; BL contains 000(A&B)b
shr al, 2 ; AL contains 000(C&D)b
xor al, bl ; AL contains 000((C&D) XOR (A&B))b
inc cl ; increment DCBA as a 4-bit number
cmp cl, 16 ; all 16 combinations?
jne L ; not yet, repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xor cx,cx               ; init counter register
repeatLoop:
mov al,cx               ; bits a,b,c and d in lowest 4 nibbles
call processtruthtable
inc cx
cmp cx,16               ; 4bits so 16 possibilities
jl repeatLoop
jmp exitProgram
processtruthtable:
....
....
....
....
ret
exitProgram:
// whatever OS you use, use the exit INT call
for dos it's INT21/4C
for linux it's INT80/01
part after / is to be stored in AH
```

correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Using a counter is the same answer that Alexey already proposed.  And BTW, I think you meant `lowest 4 bits`, or `lowest 1 nibble`, because a 16-bit word is only 4 nibbles total.